# receiving a list of all the people who done like a special picture

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want receiving a list of the people done like a special picture ,but i can't .
I use this url:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

But the result of using the url receive this json :

```
{"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
```

ََAnd if I liked the photo is registered a case

```
{"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": [{"username": "hamed.m1997", "profile_picture": "https://igcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xat1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14712441_723099691174703_691272611174285312_a.jpg", "id": "1522131692", "full_name": "hamed mansouri"}]}
```

Thanks ,for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your application in Sandbox mode you can get information only about yourself and sandbox users.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Comment: if Sandbox mode become off .does show a list of the everyone done like a special picture even users are not authentic ?